# Making a BrainF*ck Interpreter, trouble with Loops

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Here is my code http://pastebin.com/itL26LW6 http://pastebin.com/index/fvx3Tc65

In particular this is the part that is supposed to control the [ and ]

```
 case Token.LEFT:
                    if (tape[datapointer] == 0 ){
                            int i =1;
                            while (i > 0) {
                                    char c2 = (char) c[++charpointer];
                                    if (c2 == Token.LEFT)
                                            i++;
                                    else if (c2 == Token.RIGHT)
                                            i--;   
                            }
                    }
                    break;
            case Token.RIGHT:
                    int i = 1;
                    while ( i > 0 ) {
                            char c2 = (char) c[--charpointer];
                            if (c2 == Token.LEFT)  
                                    i--;
                            else if (c2 == Token.RIGHT)
                                    i++;
                    }
                    charpointer--;
                    break;

            }
```

}

The program is supposed to read in a brainf*ck program in a file called file.txt. The problem is, I tested with hello world and my program doesn't do anything. I can't figure out the problem with the above code algorithm.

Comment: The program works fine with programs without the [ and ]

Comment: Now because of the '*' we will never know what you meant.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem.  Otherwise, tell us what issues remain and we'll try to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that after a `[` token your `charpointer` is not incremented.

This means that if the value under the current `datapointer` is non-zero, your program gets stuck on the `[` symbol because `++charpointer` isn't executed even once.
And if `datapointer` is pointing to a zero, it jumps onto the corresponding `]`, causing an infinite loop.

Also, after a `]` token the `charpointer` *should not* be decremented, otherwise your program jumps onto the token *before* the `]`, which is wrong.

Here's the corrected code:

```java
case Token.LEFT:
  if (tape[datapointer] == 0) { 
    int i = 1;
    while (i > 0) {
      char c2 = (char) c[++charpointer];
      if (c2 == Token.LEFT) 
        i++;
      else if (c2 == Token.RIGHT) 
        i--;    
    }
  }
  charpointer ++;
  break;
case Token.RIGHT:
  int i = 1;
  while ( i > 0 ) {
    char c2 = (char) c[--charpointer];
    if (c2 == Token.LEFT)   
      i--;
    else if (c2 == Token.RIGHT) 
      i++;
  }
  break;
```